# How to equally bin a variable based on another value for that variable?

Tags: python, binning

I have data that summarizes jobs across different areas, grouped by the default delivery radius for the regions so it looks like this

```
radius_km   num_jobs
3.0          37745
5.0          327963
6.0          259885
7.0          145021
8.0          128145
9.0          280185
10.0         790295
11.0         72166
12.0         1872242
13.0         152221
14.0         202767
15.0         477996
16.0         33438
20.0         17098
```

I am trying to bin together the different radius groups so that there is now X groups (keeping the radius continuity in mind e.g. 3-5km, 6-10km) with as close to equal sum of num_jobs in each bin as possible.

I've been trying to use pd.cut or pd.qcut but I can't seem to get what I'm looking for out of these.

My expected results would look like this:

```
radius_km_bin  num_jobs
3.0 - 9.0         x
10.0 - 12.0       y
13.0 - 20         z
```

Where x ~ y ~ z

The ranges I chose here are just to illustrate the format, not the actual desired ranges.

Answer (score 2):

here's a horrendously hacky approach I'm almost ashamed to share, but gets the job done (assuming you're breaking it into 3 bins) and hopefully it will give you an idea how to do it..this is a simple optimization problem but because you are essentially optimizing how to slice your df, the indices are integers and it becomes an integer programming issue which is not easy in python

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
res=np.empty([0,3]) #empty np array
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv') #read in df
new = pd.DataFrame(columns=['radius_km_bin','num_jobs']) #output df
num_jobs = df.num_jobs.values #assign values to array

for i in range(len(num_jobs)-2): #first split in array
    for j in range(i+1,len(num_jobs)-1): #second split in array
        diff1=abs(sum(num_jobs[:i])-sum(num_jobs[i:j])) #diff between 1st/2nd chunk
        diff2=abs(sum(num_jobs[i:j])-sum(num_jobs[j:])) #diff between 2nd/3rd chunk
        tmp = np.array([[i,j,diff2+diff1]]) #combined error
        res = np.append(res,tmp,axis=0) #save i,j,error to array

i,j = int(res[res[:,2]==min(res[:,2]),0][0]),int(res[res[:,2]==min(res[:,2]),1][0]) #find i,j corresponding to min error, convert to int for indexing

new['radius_km_bin'] = [' '.join([str(kms[0]),'-',str(kms[0:i][-1])]),' '.join([str(kms[i]),'-',str(kms[i:j][-1])]),' '.join([str(kms[j]),'-',str(kms[-1])])] #join kms into string for output dataframe

new['num_jobs'] = [sum(df['num_jobs'][0:i]),sum(df['num_jobs'][i:j]),sum(df['num_jobs'][j:])] #sum num_jobs within the chunks
```

output :

```
  radius_km_bin  num_jobs
0        3 - 10   1969239
1       11 - 12   1944408
2       13 - 20    883520
```

I'm sure there's a better way to do it, but hopefully this leads you in the direction

EDIT - a better way :

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def diffs(x):
    diff1=abs(sum(num_jobs[:int(x[0])])-sum(num_jobs[int(x[0]):int(x[1])]))
    diff2=abs(sum(num_jobs[int(x[0]):int(x[1])])-sum(num_jobs[int(x[1]):]))
    diff3=abs(sum(num_jobs[:int(x[0])])-sum(num_jobs[int(x[1]):]))
    return sum([diff1,diff2,diff3])

r = minimize(diffs,x,method='Powell')

i,j = int(r.x[0]),int(r.x[1])
```

with this I get the same answer